# InvokeRequired is false when opening form for second time

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, desktop-application

I have created windows forms application with target framework 4.7.2. I am doing USB communication with device. I have 4 buttons on UI from which 2 button enable(connect and disconnect) and 2 disabled(download data and download log), when I click on Connect Device button. I send command to device and receive response. I verify device id is stored in my application or not, if it is stored then I enable those 2 disabled buttons and display one green signal. When I click on disconnect, I disable those 2 enabled button and signal with red color.

**This is perfectly working fine when I open form for first time. When I close that form and again open it, InvokeRequired is getting false for all controls.**

Below is code snippet.

Opening form from home form.

```
MenuSystem menuSystem = new MenuSystem();
menuSystem.Show();
```

Disabling buttons from MenuSystem form.

```cs
if (btnDownloadData.InvokeRequired)
    btnDownloadData.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { btnDownloadData.Enabled = true; });
 else
    btnDownloadData.Enabled = true;
 if (btnDownloadLogData.InvokeRequired)
    btnDownloadLogData.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { btnDownloadLogData.Enabled = true; });
 else
    btnDownloadLogData.Enabled = true;
 if (lblDeviceConnection.InvokeRequired)
    lblDeviceConnection.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { lblDeviceConnection.BackColor = Color.Green; });
 else
   lblDeviceConnection.BackColor = Color.Green;
```

I tried using timer and background worker but in all cases I am getting InvokeRequired is false and I have written else case as well to modify GUI, but it is also not reflecting on UI.

You help is truly appreciated.

Comment: Firstly, unless there's other code between them, there's no point in three separate `if...else` statements. You're marshalling to the same UI thread in all 3 cases, so doing it 3 times is creating unnecessary overhead. Just use the `InvokeRequired` and `Invoke` members of the form and marshal to the UI thread once to perform all 3 actions.

Comment: As for your issue, `InvokeRequired` will be `false` if you are currently executing on the thread that created the control. If it's `false` in your case then either you created the form on the UI thread and you're executing on the UI thread or you created the form on a secondary thread and you're executing on that same secondary thread. I'm going to guess that it's the latter in your case but you haven't provided enough information for us to be able to tell. You need to debug your code, which would include checking the current thread ID at various critical points to see what thread you're on.

Comment: We need a [mcve] to be able to tell you what's going on. Otherwise all we can say is that you've made a mistake with which thread you're running on when you created the controls and when you are using your timer/background worker.

Comment: InvokeRequired, only indicate if the control is accessible or not. It's no help to see if there is already one window open.

Comment: `InvokeRequired` returns `false` also when the Form instance has been closed. You cannot test that from a secondary Thread. Avoid all that, don't invoke any UI elements from a secondary Thread (you should use the Form as mashaller, BTW, not child Controls). Marshal state (or data) instead, possibly with a [Progress<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1) delegate

Answer (score -1):

**Edit:**

If you close a non-modal form (ie. you opened it by `Show()` rather than `ShowDialog()`), then it automatically gets disposed. Also meaning that `Invoke`/`InvokeRequired` will not work anymore.

Of course, if some task is still running on another thread, you need to be prepared to be able to cancel it (alternatively, you need to prevent the form from closing) and it still can be possible that the form will have been disposed by the time the task can be stopped. If you invoke callbacks after such a task is finished, it may happen that the controls to be updated are already disposed, too. But the original answer covers this issue.

---

**Original answer** - a solution for an edge case when `InvokeRequired` returns `false` on a non-disposed form

Though you didn't provide a reproducible example, I also experienced that in certain cases `InvokeRequired` may return `false` incorrectly. In my experience it may happen when you query `InvokeRequired` before creating the handle of the form. In the end I came up with the following solution:

```cs
// assuming you might need this in multiple views I created a base form here
public partial class MyBaseForm : Form
{
    // to identify "manually" whether an invoke is required
    private readonly int threadId;

    // to delay Invoke until it can actually work
    private readonly ManualResetEventSlim handleCreated;

    protected MyBaseForm()
    {
        threadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        handleCreated = new ManualResetEventSlim();

        // and here your usual constructor stuff...
        InitializeComponent();    
    }

    // The core of the solution. Use this in your derived forms instead of Invoke.
    protected void InvokeIfRequired(Action action)
    {
        if (Disposing || IsDisposed)
            return;

        try
        {
            // No invoke is required (not using InvokeRequired because 
            // that may return false if handle is not created yet)
            if (threadId == Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)
            {
                action.Invoke();
                return;
            }

            // The handle is not created yet: we must wait; otherwise, Invoke will fail.
            // Note: we are on a foreign thread now so we can block it safely.
            if (!handleCreated.IsSet)
                handleCreated.Wait();

            // Calling the actual Control.Invoke. Now it should work.
            Invoke(action);
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException)
        {
            // It can happen that though Disposing and IsDisposed both returned
            // false, Invoke started to execute our delegate after disposing
        }
    }

    // This is the moment from where InvokeRequired and Invoke work properly.
    // Though we don't use InvokeRequired anymore we still need it for Invoke.
    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        handleCreated.Set();
    }

    // If you didn't touch it, this might be in your MyBaseForm.Designer.cs,
    // in which case it is recommended to move it here
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            components?.Dispose();
            handleCreated.Dispose();

            // and your custom cleanup here
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

And then you can use it like this:

```cs
public partial class MenuSystem : MyBaseForm
{
    // [...]

    private void SomeMethodThatMayExecuteOnAnyThread()
    {
        // ... some code that can be safely executed on any thread

        // and the moment when a callback might be needed:
        InvokeIfRequired(() =>
        {
            btnDownloadData.Enabled = true;
            btnDownloadLogData.Enabled = true;
            lblDeviceConnection.BackColor = Color.Green;
        });
    }
}
```

And [here](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.Drawing.Tools/blob/master/KGySoft.Drawing.ImagingTools/View/Forms/MvvmBaseForm.cs) you can find a live example (`InvokeIfRequired` is actually private there but that doesn't change the point.)